# Grails: eager loading doesn't work

Tags: java, hibernate, grails, grails-orm, eager-loading

I want to access the list of organisations from a user object within the main.gsp:

```
<g:select name="effectiveOrganisation"
from="${session.user.organisations}" optionKey="id" optionValue="name"
value="${session.effectiveOrganisation?.id}" />
```

The user object is defined by the following class:

```
class SystemUser {

    static hasMany = [organisations: Organisation]
    static belongsTo = [Organisation]
    static mapping = {
        organisations lazy: false
    }

}
```

But when I execute my code, I get:

```
Exception Message: could not initialize proxy - no Session
Caused by: Error executing tag <g:form>: 
Error executing tag <g:select>: could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

Why does the eager not work here?

Comment: Are you sure this is a problem with eager fetching? Looks more like a problem with the Session.

Comment: Shouldn't the session be irrelevant when accessing eager fetched attributes?

Comment: Yes. Http session is irrelevant (not the Hibernate Session). I suggest there is a problem with the http session not the Hibernate session - so you're not even getting to hibernate. In other words - the error message you get has nothing to do with GORM I suspect.

Comment: I was referring to the hibernate session. The http session works correctly for other http session attributes.

Comment: Does it work without eager fetching then?

Comment: Is session.user available at all? Maybe it's user that is wrapped into lazy proxy? Will you try rendering just an user name.
Can you pass User explicitly in a model, what then?

Comment: Does `from="${SystemUser.get(session.user.id).organisations}"` work?

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear from your code, but I'm going to assume that you have a many-to-many here based on the `belongsTo` property.

I've managed to reproduce this with Grails 1.3.5. The problem only seems to affect the side of the relationship that has the `belongsTo` property. If you tried the same code with organization -> users instead, it would work.

The fix is rather odd: make the `users` collection on `Organization` non-lazy too.

This one will have to make it into the GORM Gotchas series!